# Need IPv4 equivalent of /proc/net/dev_snmp6

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel

I need to fetch IPv4 statistics similar to /proc/net/dev_snmp6. I am on Ubuntu 14.04.1
dev_snmp6 gives a detailed statistics as below. I need similar one for v4

```
ifIndex                             2
Ip6InReceives                       22
Ip6InHdrErrors                      0
Ip6InTooBigErrors                   0
Ip6InNoRoutes                       0
Ip6InAddrErrors                     0
Ip6InUnknownProtos                  0
Ip6InTruncatedPkts                  0
Ip6InDiscards                       0
Ip6InDelivers                       22
Ip6OutForwDatagrams                 0
Ip6OutRequests                      34
Ip6OutDiscards                      0
Ip6OutNoRoutes                      0
Ip6ReasmTimeout                     0
Ip6ReasmReqds                       0
Ip6ReasmOKs                         0
Ip6ReasmFails                       0
Ip6FragOKs                          0
Ip6FragFails                        0
Ip6FragCreates                      0
Ip6InMcastPkts                      22
Ip6OutMcastPkts                     42
Ip6InOctets                         3724
Ip6OutOctets                        4584
Ip6InMcastOctets                    3724
Ip6OutMcastOctets                   5212
Ip6InBcastOctets                    0
Ip6OutBcastOctets                   0
Ip6InNoECTPkts                      22
Ip6InECT1Pkts                       0
Ip6InECT0Pkts                       0
Ip6InCEPkts                         0
Icmp6InMsgs                         0
Icmp6InErrors                       0
Icmp6OutMsgs                        12
Icmp6OutErrors                      0
Icmp6InCsumErrors                   0
Icmp6InDestUnreachs                 0
Icmp6InPktTooBigs                   0
Icmp6InTimeExcds                    0
Icmp6InParmProblems                 0
Icmp6InEchos                        0
Icmp6InEchoReplies                  0
Icmp6InGroupMembQueries             0
Icmp6InGroupMembResponses           0
Icmp6InGroupMembReductions          0
Icmp6InRouterSolicits               0
Icmp6InRouterAdvertisements         0
Icmp6InNeighborSolicits             0
Icmp6InNeighborAdvertisements       0
Icmp6InRedirects                    0
Icmp6InMLDv2Reports                 0
Icmp6OutDestUnreachs                0
Icmp6OutPktTooBigs                  0
Icmp6OutTimeExcds                   0
Icmp6OutParmProblems                0
Icmp6OutEchos                       0
Icmp6OutEchoReplies                 0
Icmp6OutGroupMembQueries            0
Icmp6OutGroupMembResponses          0
Icmp6OutGroupMembReductions         0
Icmp6OutRouterSolicits              3
Icmp6OutRouterAdvertisements        0
Icmp6OutNeighborSolicits            1
Icmp6OutNeighborAdvertisements      0
Icmp6OutRedirects                   0
Icmp6OutMLDv2Reports                8
Icmp6OutType133                     3
Icmp6OutType135                     1
Icmp6OutType143                     8
```

Comment: /proc/net/snmp, but it's something you'll have to parse into pieces.

Comment: But it is a system wide statistics. We need per interface statistics.

Answer (score 0):

/proc/net/dev check this file

```
Inter-|   Receive                                                |  Transmit


face |bytes    packets errs drop fifo frame compressed multicast|bytes    packets errs drop fifo colls carrier compressed
lo: 17601481   83195    0    0    0     0          0         0 17601481   83195    0    0    0     0       0          0
```

eth0: 88304516 1392082    0    0    0     0          0         0   174173    1109    0    0    0     0       0          0